# Query range in activeworkbook using ADODB

Tags: vba, adodb

I'm trying to write some VBA that can query a named range in VBA using SQL. Currently, it works reasonably well, but i have the problem that every time i run the macro a read-only instance of the worksheet is opened. I want to use the macro to query ranges within the same workbook without opening a read-only copy.

Here is my code

```
Public Sub QueryAndOutputToCell(ByVal query As String, rng As Range)

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim DBFullName, connString, SQL As String
DBFullName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.name

connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & DBFullName & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
conn.connectionString = connString
conn.Open ' Read-only copy is opened here
conn.commandtimeout = 0

Dim cubeData As ADODB.Recordset
Set cubeData = New ADODB.Recordset

cubeData.Open query, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

rng.CopyFromRecordset cubeData

cubeData.Close
conn.Close
Set cubeData = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Do anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: An ADO connection is not a workbook open or copy event. Does your data not fill in at `CopyFromRecordset`?

Comment: Hi Parfait, yes it does. It seems to load data from the read-only copy of the work book and not the workbook from which the macro was called. I can see this by editing the data without saving and running the macro

Comment: Where is this macro being run? On the same workbook? If both are the same, the ADO connection will use the last saved data. Try saving before recordset call.

Comment: The macro is being run in the same workbook as the data range that i want to query. I tried to save the workbook just before i open the connection, but it still opens up a read-only copy of the workbook

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue. I added `ThisWorkbook.Save` just before connection call. Then I made changes to worksheet query runs on (w/o manually saving), and sure enough, updated and new data came through resultset. Please show attempted SQL query.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Maybe similar to this: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/13256-advanced-using-ado-to-read-from-activeworkbook

Comment: thanks Parfait, will check back in monday

Comment: @TimWilliams Interesting.. Could be the problem. I'll check up on it monday